# R Alternative to geom_jitter

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot, boxplot

I would like to plot a scatterplot on my boxplots, but I am having trouble with controlling the "randomness" of the geom_jitter function.
Below is the boxplot without the scatterplot.
[image: Boxplot without scatterplot]

The code is as following:

```
dev.new()
ggplot(data=Original,
aes(x=factor(first), y=Age, fill=observer))+
ggtitle("Cortical Bone")+
theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size=15))+
geom_boxplot()+
labs(fill="Observer", x="Variants")
```

As you can see, there are 2 observers. However, when using geom_jitter, it results in a scatterplot that is in a random location between variants rather than between observers. I am wondering if there is a function that allows each point to be separated between observers as well for each variant.

Update:
geom_jitter(width=0.25) nor geom_jitter(height=0.25) worked (images below, with top being width and bottom being height), as I know that for variant 1, each observer should have 2 observations.
[image: width0.25]

[image]

Comment: Could you not control the ‘randomness’ of the jitter by using, say, ```geom_jitter(width = 0.25)``` or possibly ```height``` parameter?

Comment: width or height parameters did not work - I have updated by question to show how they did not work

Comment: Instead of `geom_jitter()`, try `geom_point(aes(group = observer), position = position_jitterdodge())`.

Comment: position=position_jitterdodge(dodge=0.6) seems to work. Thank you everyone for your help!